# Can we access cloud data of User slot from other Users in the room of RealtimeMultiPlayer

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer

i am working on a game - using Google Play Game Services, working on RealTime Multi Player, we have [cloudsave](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave) option on google play game services.

on API showing this information

Applications that use the Cloud Save service can use up to four different sets of data, or slots, to save and load data for each user. Each slot is identified by an integer, or key, from 0 to 3 and can hold up to 256 kilobytes of data, for a total storage size of 1024 kilobytes.

Each data slot can be updated independently of the other slots, which enables several options for managing application data. For example, you can use the slots to manage multiple saved games for a user. You could also use the slots to create separately managed data segments that can be updated independently, and thereby minimize data upload sizes and reduce network bandwidth consumption. If your application is an adventure game, for example, you can store a player's inventory in one slot, while storing the appearance of their in-game character in another. If the player then changed their character's hair color, you can then update their character's appearance without having to re-upload the player's entire inventory.

My Question is can we access user1 data from user2. is that possible? then how?

Answer (score 0):

While you can't directly access it, it would be possible for your app to request that data from other players, and have the data sent over via message.

So Player1 and Player2 connect to a room.  Player1 sends request for data to Player2, and Player2 sends request for Player1 data... upon receipt, Player1 and Player2 both access the data in their Cloud Save, and send the data back to the other..(or not, based on whatever parameters you set up)